# consulta entre 2 tabelas laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a tabelas produtos(tbl_produtos) e a tabela categorias(tbl_categorias):

```
- tbl_produtos -
id_produto
nome
id_categoria

- tbl_categorias -
id_categoria
nome
```

O que quero é: apresentar na view a lista de produtos, em que por cada produto, diz o nome da categoria que está relacionada. Qual será a melhor opção para fazer esta consulta? No model ou há problema de fazer no controller?

No meu controller tenho o seguinte:

```
public function getIndex(){
    $produtos= ProdutoDados::get(); 
    return View::make('produtos.lista', compact('produtos')); 
}
```

No model dos produtos tenho apenas o seguinte:

```
<?php
    class ProdutosDados extends Eloquent{
        protected $table = 'tbl_produtos';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id_produto';
        protected $guarded = array('id_produto'); 
    }
?>
```

Model categorias:

```
<?php
    class CategoriaDados extends Eloquent{
        protected $table = 'tbl_categorias';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id_categoria';
        protected $guarded = array('id_categoria'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Como está o relacionamento entre seus models?

Comment: Fiz a alteração na pergunta @gmsantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer...

Mas tem duas que sempre uso.
Usando JOIN no Laravel ou usando funções de relacionamentos no Model correspondente.

Usando JOIN:

```
$query = DB::table('tbl_produtos')
             ->join('tbl_categorias', 'tbl_produtos.id_categoria', '=', 'tbl_categoria.id')
             ->select('tbl_produtos.nome as Produto', 'tbl_categorias.nome as Categoria')
             ->get();
```

Usando Relacionamento no Model - O link abaixo pode te ajudar.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one